# Find object property's index by property's value

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, I am trying to get the index of the object property who shares the value of a clicked button. I know the object's index to search, `counter`, but need to get the object property and it's index. For example, if I click the button with a value of "Poised", I need to return index of 'item2', which is 1.

```js
var questions = [{
    'item1': 'Alert',
    'item2': 'Poised',
    'item3': 'Ready',
    'item4': 'Eager'
  },
  {
    'item1': 'Patient',
    'item2': 'Diligent',
    'item3': 'Forceful',
    'item4': 'Prepared'
  }
]

counter = 0
buttonValue = "Poised"

console.log(questions[counter])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not flip your object's keys and values? That way you can just do obj["Poised"]? Either that or give your button a different value ("item2") than it's displayed text ("Poised")

Comment: I sightly misunderstood your question as well. JavaScript objects do not have indexes, they purely rely on keys which are not in any specific order, so you can't get an index from an object unless your key is a number and you treat it as an index. I would have to ask for more context about why these are objects in the first place before advising you on any solution.

Comment: Why not just return the key `"object2"`?

Comment: How are you going to use this "index" once you have it? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)...

Answer (score 0):

As @obermillerk said, JavaScript objects do not have indexes.
but you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the index from the array which basically includes the values of that object, by the order of its values.

```js
var questions = [{
    'item1': 'Alert',
    'item2': 'Poised',
    'item3': 'Ready',
    'item4': 'Eager'
  },
  {
    'item1': 'Patient',
    'item2': 'Diligent',
    'item3': 'Forceful',
    'item4': 'Prepared'
  }
];            

var index;
questions.forEach(obj => {
  var value = Object.values(obj).indexOf('Poised');
 if(value !== -1) {
    index = value;
  }
})

console.log(index);
```

Comment: I don't know that the order of the result of Object.values is guaranteed.

Comment: Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that they are in the expected order, just that the order is the same as a for loop. It may be that they are in the right order but that does not prove it and it may vary by JavaScript implementation